# What does autoRegenerate from cakephp 2

Tags: session, countdown

Can someone explain me what does exactly Session.autoRegenerate from cakephp ? I have already read [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html) but unfortunatly it's still not clear for me...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the documentation is not very clear about this. Through experimentation I come to the following conclusion:

The sole purpose of Session.autoRegenerate is to restart the session with a new session ID. This is for security reasons only because it makes session hijacking more difficult. If you do not care to much about Session hijacking in your application you can turn this feature off. There are some issues with this feature, e.g. if you have many ajax request on the same page the session might get regenerated and the following ajax requests would be done with an invalid session ID which will result in a 403 error code.

With the CakeSession::$requestCountdown parameter you can configure after how many requests the Session is regenerated. This can help to work around the difficulties described in the former paragraph.